# Very heavy cypher MATCH query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have graph with different types of nodes and edges. I would like to get all paths between two nodes (index WORD) which are connected by edges (relation NEXT_WORD) with property edgeLevel=1. I don't want to get connections where "edgeLevel != 1". I wrote a query

```
MATCH p=(a:WORD{wholeWord:"are"})-[r:NEXT_WORD*1..3{edgeLevel:1}]->(b:WORD{wholeWord: "you"}) RETURN length(p);
```

but it is very heavy. I'm trying to figure out how to optimize this cypher query, but I have no idea. Is there any quicker and less heavy way to do this? This query returned 32 rows in 7931 ms.

[image: Cypher PROFILE query]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to already have an index on `:WORD(wholeWord)`. However, your query is not using the index to find both `a` and `b`. This query should be faster:

```
MATCH p=(a:WORD { wholeWord:"are" })-[r:NEXT_WORD*..3 {edgeLevel:1}]->(b:WORD { wholeWord: "you" })
USING INDEX a:WORD(wholeWord)
USING INDEX b:WORD(wholeWord)
RETURN length(p);
```

But your query can be even faster if you do not require a specific property value for your relationship (because of fewer DB hits), especially since there  is no way to create an index for relationships. So, if you could use a `[:NEXT_WORD_1]` relationship instead of a `[:NEXT_WORD {edgeLevel:1}]` relationship, this would be the fastest:

```
MATCH p=(a:WORD { wholeWord:"are" })-[r:NEXT_WORD_1*..3]->(b:WORD { wholeWord: "you" })
USING INDEX a:WORD(wholeWord)
USING INDEX b:WORD(wholeWord)
RETURN length(p);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However adding USING INDEX b:WORD(wholeWord) didn't speed up the query. Previous query cost: 378082 total db hits, Your first proposition: planner: RULE. 10984317 total db hits. Adding new relation NEXT_WORD_1 is rather workaround to this situation, but I think this is the only option which left. I will try reimplement this graph structure and I will give you the answer in next comment.

Comment: I have implemented new types of relation and it's working now quicker. My query with new type of relation `NEXT_WORD_1` planner: COST. 61194 total db hits in 188 ms. Your first solution (with using two indexes and `NEXT_WORD_1`) planner: RULE. 19993 total db hits in 172 ms.